# Using JSPDF to convert web page to pdf : 'Uint8Array' is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

I'm trying to convert a form from a web page to a pdf using jspdf. I have a button that is supposed to trigger the creation of the pdf but I get this error when I push it:

0x800a1391 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Uint8Array' is undefined

When I try to open it in Chrome, I get a blank pdf and no error.

The error is caused by this line in the second file here:

```
var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(length));
```

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4715183

I'm assuming that since it creates a blank pdf, the problem is with the buffer trying to read in data. I have no clue what I'm doing so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Uint8Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/br212477%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) wasn't available until Internet Explorer 10.

[Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com/#search=uint8array) indicates that Typed Arrays were available starting in Firefox 4 and Chrome 7.